# can't get oracle function result into java(ejb)

Tags: java, oracle, function, ejb, sys-refcursor

I have oracle function which returns sys_refcursor.

```
create or replace function get_person_salaries(p_year  in number,
                                                   p_month in number)
      return sys_refcursor
```

and I want to call from ejb(java). how to do this? how can i get all the result list of sys_refcursor?

Thanks

Comment: Hope! This might help you. [Link] (http://stackoverflow.com/a/6782009/2244720)

Comment: Thank you for your response but I want to access that function from java and not from oracle. I already know how to do it from oracle.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like that should work:

```
Connection conn = getConnection(); 
CallableStatement call =
  conn.prepareCall ("{ ? = call java_refcursor.job_listing (?, ?)}");

call.registerOutParameter (1, OracleTypes.CURSOR); // this is a key line
call.setString (2, arg1);
call.setString (3, arg2);
call.execute ();
ResultSet rs = (ResultSet)call.getObject (1); // Just casting sys_refcursor to ResultSet
while (rs .next ())
  System.out.println (rs.getString(1));
```

The way to get connection in ejb:

```
@Stateless
public class YourBean {

    @Resource(lookup = "java:/jdbc/yourdatasource")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
       return connection = dataSource.getConnection());        
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but i have not conn object, because I use EntityManager(Jpa)

Comment: @vssk call.setString(1,arg1) is wrong because position 1 is already reserved for OracleTypes.CURSOR (return argument)

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Corrected

Comment: gogagubi, you always can use @Resouce annotation to lookup datasource. I've made changes in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to use Entity Manager, if your container is EE7 compliant, then JPA 2.1 should be supported,  in this case you can create a JPA query that invokes a stored procedure. An example from PRO JPA book that seems similar to your needs, is as follows,  :

```
StoredProcedureQuery q = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("fetch_emp");
q.registerStoredProcedureParameter("empList", void.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);
if (q.execute()) {
List<Employee> emp = (List<Employee>)q.getOutputParameterValue("empList");
// ...
}
```

Also like @NamedQuery, in JPA 2.1 you can create @NamedStoredProcedure as follows:

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
name="fetch_emp",
procedureName="fetch_emp",
parameters={
@StoredProcedureParameter(name="empList", type=void.class,
mode=ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR)
},
resultClasses=Employee.class)
```

Comment: in that case how pass parameters ? i have parameters p_year, p_month

Comment: Use one of "Query" "setParameter" methods.